# Automatically convert cooking recipe units

Tags: ios, automation, notes.app, text

I am looking for a way to manipulate cooking recipe texts in such a way, that measurement in units foreign to me are converted to the ones I know. For example:

*2 cups* of milk → *568 ml* of milk

Here is what I think needs to happen:

1. Look for {Number}{Space}{Unit}{Space}.
2. Replace foreign unit with known unit.
3. Multiply and round number to represent appropriate value in the new unit.

I was thinking of using GREP to achieve this, but do not know how to apply GREP to, say, a note in the Notes app, or text in TextEdit. But I have an open mind as to how this might be achieved.  Ideally this would be possible inside the Notes app on my iPhone however, since this is the place where I gather cooking recipes.

Comment: First off, `grep` *finds lines matching a pattern.*. Maybe you're thinking `awk` or `sed`?  That said, (hey, that rhymes!) are you trying to do this in Bash, AppleScript, JavaScript, or a different language?  What have you gotten so far?  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @Allan When I look at your comment, I guess my question should have really been phrased "Please point in the direction I need to go, to be able to accomplish this task for my notes on iPhone." Sorry for noobing around, I only recently started tipping my toes into scripting. Thank you already for clarification.

Comment: It's not my favorite environment, but since you want to do this in Notes, I would look at AppleScript.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a shortcut I’ve made that does this: [**Apply Conversions**](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/151c7cd82a944715b055265d5f0c1a26).

Given input, either from

- a note (tap the Share button in the upper-right)
- selected text in any app (tap Share from the selection menu)
- the current clipboard (run the shortcut from the app or the widget)

the output will be produced. See the example below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

When importing the shortcut from the link above, you will be asked to enter your conversions. These can be edited at any time by editing the shortcut.

[image]

The shortcut is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Holy shit, that is enormously helpful! Thanks man! I get some undesired results here and there and will try to tweak the shortcut to account for these. I will report back when I think that I improved it.